# How can I fix : "Cannot read properties of undefined( reading 'role')" I believe its a mongodb/mongoose issue. How can I fix database request issue?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am currently getting problems reading `role` on my postman POST request on backend nodejs express. I was wondering how would i go about fixing this?

below is the route for authentication in my middleware/auth.js

```
 exports.isAuthenticatedUser = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {

    const { token } = req.cookies

    if (!token) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler('Login first to access this resource.', 401))
    }

    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
    req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id);

    next()
})

// Handling users roles
exports.authorizeRoles = (...roles) => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        if (!roles.includes(req.user.role)) {
            return next(
                new ErrorHandler(`Role (${req.user.role}) is not allowed to acccess this resource`, 403))
        }
        next()
    }
}
```

I have added in extra information. Hopefully this helps clear up some missing background info. But the ideas is to show you where ```decoded.id`` comes from (getJwtToken). which by the way is used in the registration process of user accounts. which I also share at the bottom.

addition to models/users.js :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const crypto = require('crypto')

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter your name'],
        maxLength: [30, 'Your name cannot exceed 30 characters']
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter your email'],
        unique: true,
        validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Please enter valid email address']
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter your password'],
        minlength: [6, 'Your password must be longer than 6 characters'],
        select: false
    },
    avatar: {
        public_id: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        url: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        default: 'user'
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpire: Date

})

userSchema.methods.getJwtToken = function () {
    return jwt.sign({ id: this._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_TIME
    });
}
```

controllers/authController.js

```
exports.registerUser = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {

    const result = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.body.avatar, {
        folder: 'avatars',
        width: 150,
        crop: "scale"
    })

    const { name, email, password } = req.body;

    const user = await User.create({
        name,
        email,
        password,
        avatar: {
            public_id: result.public_id,
            url: result.secure_url
        }
    })

    sendToken(user, 200, res)

})
```

and your utils/jwtToken.js

```
const sendToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {

    // Create Jwt token
    const token = user.getJwtToken();

    // Options for cookie
    const options = {
        expires: new Date(
            Date.now() + process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRES_TIME * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
        ),
        httpOnly: true
    }


    res.status(statusCode).cookie('token', token, options).json({
        success: true,
        token,
        user
    })

}

module.exports = sendToken;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to your user to be undefined. You should handle that case, but if you don't want for any reason you can just check it is not null using `req.user?.role`:

```
exports.authorizeRoles = (...roles) => {
return (req, res, next) => {
    if (!roles.includes(req.user?.role)) {
        return next(
            new ErrorHandler(`Role (${req.user?.role}) is not allowed to acccess this resource`, 403))
    }
    next()
}
}
```

In this case, if the user is not defined the role will be undefined too (returning the same error of `Role (${req.user.role}) is not allowed to acccess this resource`)

**NULL CHECK USER**

```
exports.authorizeRoles = (...roles) => {
if (!req.user) //throw error (user doesn't exist in db)
return (req, res, next) => {
    if (!roles.includes(req.user.role)) {
        return next(
            new ErrorHandler(`Role (${req.user.role}) is not allowed to acccess this resource`, 403))
    }
    next()
}
}
```

Comment: thank you for your input. I made the change you shared and its still showing,  ```Cannot read properties of undefined( reading 'role')```. How can i make sure the user is defined?  From my assumptions, user already has a a schema where its created as well as its role. So it should be defined. any input will help. Essentially how can i get user to be defined so that my role is define? - thank you

Comment: @ThatGuynick Have you changed the string in the message too? That may be the reason why you keep receiving that error

Comment: @ThatGuynick The user can always be undefined: maybe the client is sending a wrong token, or the id doesn't match with the database, so it is always better to make a null check. I edited my answer including that scenario, you just have to throw the exception where I commented with the message you want, in that way you display 2 different error messages if the user doesn't exists in the db or doesn't have permission based in its role.

Comment: yep. I am getting user does not exist. I am assuming the next step is to look at my userSchema and make sure that it routes well? In my case user is registered in db. So i am lost here :/ @Igor Cantele

Comment: With the information you are giving here it's impossible to say what it is. Are you sure `decoded.id` is what you expect it to be? if it is, the problem is definetely related to your request to the db, otherwise it's on the token side. When you understand what's the problem you should post another question with more information related to your jwt or schema setup! :)

Comment: i have added in a little bit of info. As for your comment, decoded.id was expected since its relates to userSchema and its getJwtToken function  as shown above. lmk what you think. looking forward to hearing back- thanks!

Comment: If the token's ok then the problem should be with mongoose. The code looks okay, but unfortunately I'm not really familiar with the tool so I'm not sure I can help any further... I suggest you to open a new question with the info and updated tags!

Comment: i made some changes, and the resultant is ```Role (${req.user.role}) is not allowed to acccess this resource``` plus a logging of  ```undefined``` so its safe to assume that the user is created but role is somehow not being fetched. at the very least i got a different error other than the one i shared

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `isAuthenticatedUser` in `getAllProducts` route
like this way ->

```
router.route("/products").get(isAuthenticatedUser, authorizeRoles("admin"), getAllProducts);
```

Hope It will work for you